# sql server query how to have multiple column comparision with subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

How can I make the update query to work based on the sub query?
How can I compare all these columns in the sub query to the columns in the update statement?
Is there some neat and clean way to do it?

The query I am trying with it is shown below:

```
UPDATE Temp_CropData
SET RecordStatus = 0, 
    Remarks = ISNULL(Remarks, '') +' Duplicate Records' 
WHERE
     (SELECT Commodity ,City,Period,CropCondition
      FROM [Temp_CropData] 
      GROUP BY DDate,Commodity,City,Period,CropCondition 
      HAVING count(*) >1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
UPDATE cd
SET RecordStatus = 0,      
    Remarks = ISNULL(Remarks, '') +' Duplicate Records'  
FROM   Temp_CropData cd   
JOIN (SELECT Commodity ,City,Period,CropCondition       
FROM [Temp_CropData]        
GROUP BY DDate,Commodity,City,Period,CropCondition        
HAVING count(*) >1) dup 
    ON cd.DDate = dup.DDate AND cd.Commodity=dup.Commodity AND cd.City = dup.City 
    AND cd.Period = dup.Period AND cd.CropCondition = dup.CropCondition
```

Answer (score 3):

Try using [`MERGE`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx):

```
MERGE INTO Temp_CropData
   USING (
          SELECT Commodity, City, Period, CropCondition
            FROM Temp_CropData
           GROUP 
              BY DDate, Commodity, City, Period, CropCondition 
          HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 
         ) AS source
      ON Temp_CropData.Commodity = source.Commodity 
         AND Temp_CropData.City = source.City
         AND Temp_CropData.Period = source.Period
         AND Temp_CropData.CropCondition = source.CropCondition
WHEN MATCHED THEN
   UPDATE
      SET RecordStatus = 0, 
          Remarks = ISNULL(Remarks, '') + ' Duplicate Records';
```

I'm slightly suspicious of the fact that your subquery's `SELECT` and `GROUP BY` clauses do not match, though (i.e. `DDate` is in the `GROUP BY` but not the `SELECT`).